# Java, How to add an object into LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have written following lines of code and seems everything is OK, however when I see result its not correct.

Here, I defined a LinkedList and adding an object into it.

```
private LinkedList<KategoriRecipeList> createListObjects() {

        LinkedList<KategoriRecipeList> list = new LinkedList<KategoriRecipeList>();
        KategoriRecipeList kategori = new KategoriRecipeList();

        for(int i=0; i<resepi.getResepiId().size(); i++) {
            kategori.setKategoriName(kategoriName);
            kategori.setResepiId(resepi.getResepiId().get(i));
            kategori.setResepiName(resepi.getResepiName().get(i).trim().replaceAll("'", ""));
            kategori.setImgLogoUri(resepi.getResepiImageURL().get(i));
            kategori.setImgMoreUri(bitmapUrls.get(i));

            Log.i("WWWWWWW", "Recipe '" + resepi.getResepiName().get(i) + "' added to list");

            list.add(kategori);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

When I see Log file the result is like this:

```
09-09 03:05:29.272: I/WWWWWWW(1250): Recipe '"Chicken Cordon Bleu"' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.272: I/WWWWWWW(1250): Recipe '"Sat-Bag"' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.272: I/WWWWWWW(1250): Recipe 'Ayam Adobo ' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.272: I/WWWWWWW(1250): Recipe 'Ayam Ber’Crumble’ & ‘Fennel’ direneh Air Roselle' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.272: I/WWWWWWW(1250): Recipe 'Ayam Dua Cara' added to list
```

I have another method which invokes above method:

```
private void storeListIntoDatabase() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Try to insert data into database.");

        LinkedList<KategoriRecipeList> listOfObjects = createListObjects();
        if(listOfObjects == null  ||  listOfObjects.size() <= 0)
            return;

        for(int i=0;  i<listOfObjects.size(); i++)
            Log.i("KKKKKKKK", "Recipe '" + listOfObjects.get(i).getResepiName() + "' added to list");
    }
```

Result in log file is like this:

```
09-09 03:05:29.297: I/KKKKKKKK(1250): Recipe 'Tongkeng Ayam Goreng dan Nasi Kari Leher Ayam' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.297: I/KKKKKKKK(1250): Recipe 'Tongkeng Ayam Goreng dan Nasi Kari Leher Ayam' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.297: I/KKKKKKKK(1250): Recipe 'Tongkeng Ayam Goreng dan Nasi Kari Leher Ayam' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.297: I/KKKKKKKK(1250): Recipe 'Tongkeng Ayam Goreng dan Nasi Kari Leher Ayam' added to list

09-09 03:05:29.297: I/KKKKKKKK(1250): Recipe 'Tongkeng Ayam Goreng dan Nasi Kari Leher Ayam' added to list
```

As you can see results are different but i expect result should be same. Where is my problem? Thanks

Comment: Isn't the result already the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line

KategoriRecipeList kategori = new KategoriRecipeList();

needs to be inside the for loop
you have to create a new object every time

Answer (score 3):

You need to create new instance on each loop otherwise same instance will be updated. Lists maintains reference to object, they don't contain copy of the object.

```
for(int i=0; i<resepi.getResepiId().size(); i++) {
    KategoriRecipeList kategori = new KategoriRecipeList();
    kategori.setKategoriName(kategoriName);
    kategori.setResepiId(resepi.getResepiId().get(i));
    ....
}
```